# How to custom animate a text in flutter with duration

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have a list of texts with duration for animation

```
List<RhymeModel> rhymePhrases = [
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'Baa, baa', startAt: 0.0, endAt: 0.2),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'black sheep', startAt: 0.3, endAt: 0.4),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'Have you', startAt: 0.5, endAt: 0.6),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'any wool?', startAt: 0.7, endAt: 0.8),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'Yes, sir,', startAt: 0.9, endAt: 1.0),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'yes, sir,', startAt: 1.1, endAt: 1.2),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'Three bags full.', startAt: 1.3, endAt: 1.4),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'One for the master,', startAt: 1.5, endAt: 1.6),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'And one for', startAt: 1.7, endAt: 1.8),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'dame,And one', startAt: 1.9, endAt: 2.0),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'for the little', startAt: 2.1, endAt: 2.2),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'boy Who lives ', startAt: 2.3, endAt: 2.4),
  RhymeModel(lyricsPhrase: 'down the lane.', startAt: 2.5, endAt: 2.6),
];
```

My objective is to animate each text with a reveal animation using the duration(Similar to what you can see when lyrics get matched with audio) how can I animate each texts with animations ?

Comment: watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JQxEEnA3ny8&ab_channel=TensorProgramming

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit

Comment: @AnmolMishra this package doesn't meet my requirements. I need to match the lyrics to the audio.

Comment: You can create timer and change text based on duration.